# Will FaceTime reveal my caller ID on an incoming call?

Tags: facetime, caller-id

Obviously if I initiate a FaceTime call then the recipient will see the caller ID that I've selected in my FaceTime settings.

However, if someone calls me at one of my *alternative* addresses, is my chosen caller ID revealed to them in any way? Or will they still only know about the address/number they used?

Answer (score 1):

For all the experience I have, calling my family in multiple IDs, the person only knows the ID that they already have, and FaceTime has no options to automatically reveal the other IDs that person uses.

I wanted to enable some automatic thing like this for myself, because I have 4 different cell numbers and 3 e-mails with FaceTime.
Still have not found how to do it.

So for you, the answer is "no, they still only know about the ID they used".